# Cordova 300ms delay

Tags: cordova, onclick, delay

Simple problem. I have a single DIV which change its background color when clicked. Here's the HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/code.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
<title>xxx</title>
</head>

<body onload="fInitializeFramework()">
<div onclick="fx()" class="fx">touch me!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
html {

  height: 100%;

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* Prevent callout to copy image, etc. when tap to hold */

  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* Prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */

  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* Prevent tap highlight color/shadow */

  -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* No element selection */

  cursor: default;                            /* Default cursor */

  touch-action: manipulation;                 /* Disable double tap to zoom */

}

.fx:active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

and the javascript:

```
function fInitializeFramework()
{
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",fRun);
  return;
}

function fRun()
{
  return;
}

function fx()
{
  return;
}
```

On Chrome on a desktop, everything is fine, the click event is triggered fast. But once turned into an apk with Cordova, on the tablet or on the phone, there is a delay between the touch on the DIV and the change of its background color.

It looks like the infamous 300ms delay. Yet, I followed everything that is recommended:

- viewport meta with width=device-width and minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0
- touch-action: manipulation,
  etc.

I tried using fasclick.js, with no result. Which is normal as it's useless since chrome 32+ as said in the documentation.

I suspected :active so I tried changing the background handling the onclick() event with javascript instead of using onclick in the HTML. Same result, delay on the tablet.

Android is 6.0. Cordova 7.0.1.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The delay to click on a touchscreen is as designed - its there to distinguish between a drag/swipe (touch and move whilst touched) and a click (touch and hold in the same place).

I encountered this with my game. The remedy in my case was to bind my code to *touchstart* - this registers much more quickly.

The interface design for my app is such that the user only ever wants to click - dragging doesn't achieve anything. In addition the code is only designed for touchscreen devices so I didn't need to worry about handling both click and *touchstart*.